# snap object by using its vertex as reference

Tags: snapping

i attach the screenshot. There's a box and a yellow dot (next to the box , near top left corner/vertex) . The yellow dot is the origin point of the box itself.

I want to move the whole box by using the top left corner (vertex) as reference so that corner will jump/snap to that yellow dot .

what is the shortest step to do it?

[image]

Comment: Is it important that the cube gets to the dot and not the dot  goes to the corner?

Answer (score 3):

In object mode, add an empty at the same location as the origin of the object:

1. Select the object, Snap Cursor to Selected
2. Add Empty (will be at cursor location)

Snap the mesh to the Empty

1. Edit the Object and select all
2. Set Snapping to Vertex (with Closest option selected)
3. Grab the mesh and drag it to the Empty so that it snaps to it

[Edit]
If you need another vertex to be snapped to the empty you could instead set the Active option in the Snapping menu and have that vertex selected last. Or simply drag the mesh to a point where that vertex is the closest, release it and then snap it.

Comment: UV but works only if the mesh vertex to set at origin is effectively the closest to the origin.

Comment: @lemon, I don't understand... do you mind elaborate?

Comment: Just give try setting the corner of the mesh you want (not only the closest) to the origin. (but this is a detail, just a remark)

Comment: I think that it was "UV" that got me confused... still don't get that part. But it's true that it only works with the closest. It would be possible to just move around the mesh so the wanted vertex gets closest before snapping or use Active instead.

Comment: UV = upvoted (not the UV map)!!

Comment: Personally, I have my snap almost permanently set to 'Vertex' and 'Active'. I find 'Closest' to be a pain.